# Misspelled tag - 'WDSL' instead of 'WSDL'

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I have come across misspelled tag, that has been used few times, therefore is not eligible for daily sweep of unused tags. It is tag [wdsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wdsl) - misspelled [wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsdl).

I am well aware of the fact, that WDSL is an actual thing (Wireless Digital Subscriber Line), but judging from the tagged questions, it is clearly a typo.

Comment: It's only 18 questions in the WDSL tag... you could easily do that in a few minutes.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I know, I'm already retagging them right now. There were approximately 30+. My question really is a "retag-request" - can some moderator merge these two and delete the wrong one?

Comment: I managed to narrow it down to only few left, skipped lunch for it, will do the rest this evening. Let's see if the wrong badge disappears over night.

Comment: WDSL will disappear over night when there aren't any questions tagged with it. Are you asking for it to be blacklisted or something?

Comment: Once a tag no longer has any questions associated to it, it will be gone within 24 hours. That should suffice in this case. So just correct and all should be well.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding - I thought that "retag-request" stands for activity when a moderator is able to rename a tag - merge it with existing. Majority of the questions that had this typo are corrected. Still working on it. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All incorrect **WDSL** tags have been removed from questions. Hopefully the unused badge will be automatically removed. Thanks for the help with retagging.